# Drag and drop insert into database

Tags: php, javascript

So I have a table which basically couples two tables through their ids.

What I would like is two sides of blocks containing those ids. And I would like to be able to drag from one side to another. When the block is dragged on the other block the database table would update itself with that value.

I have no clue how to start.
I tried to Google drag and drop but I couldn't find what I want.

If anyone could help me, it would be really great.

Comment: jquery, jqueryui, draggable and drop events is all you need. all are well documented on the jquery website (and google has hundreds of examples) then all you do on your drop event is do an ajax query passing the link keys etc to a back end php script which does the DB update accordingly.

Comment: I only I typed 4 keywords, drag drop insert and php and what I got is [13,200,000 results](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=drag+drop+insert++php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830336/jquery-drag-and-drop-and-save-to-mysql-database

Comment: You'll need 1) a server side script that updates the database, 2) a client side AJAX call that communicates with this script, 3) a Javascript drag & drop UI to trigger all this. All three components aren't hard in themselves and aren't hard to google. Do some research, do some experiments with the individual parts, then put it together.

Comment: hi, found this tutorial. drag and drop uning php and mysql, hope this helps. http://programmerblog.net/jquery-drag-drop-todo-list-php-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the final solution but generally advices how to start solving your problem:

1. **HTML/JS** (client)

   - I recommend jQuery UI for the drag/drop part. It's very simple, example: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/
   - Send the result via AJAX (get/post) to your PHP script: 
     http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
2. **PHP script** (server)

   - Validate the sent data
   - Update your Database: 
     http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/update.html

If you've specific questions, ask with code examples. :-)

Comment: I managed to do it, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI Sortable demo is an excellent start : 
http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

I use it everytime i need to sort something using drag&drop and never had a problem.